# Is it possible to pipe to a C program that uses fpurge to clear stdin?

Tags: c, unix, terminal, pipe, stdin

I've got a program that asks for input twice however in-between each input `fpurge(stdin)` is called.

So if I wanted to input "3" then "Hello World", I would try `echo "3\nHelloWorld" | program`, but the program will only read "3" then flush stdin before reading "Hello World". I've tried redirecting the program input to a named pipe and wrote to the named pipe twice one after another before closing the pipe but no luck.

Here's some pseudo-code of part of the program.

```
num = read_user_input("Insert number: ");
__fpurge(stdin);
name = read_user_input("Insert name: ");
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Where's the code for `read_user_input`? Why do you think `__fpurge` is a good thing to use?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Hey thanks for the quick reply, `read_user_input` isn't a real function that is just pseudo-code, you can assume it just uses a typical way of getting input from the user in C. Also I should've mentioned that this program was not written by me, this is a CTF crackme and I am looking for a way to insert non-printable characters into the stdin of the program.

Comment: The real code in place of `read_user_input` is important, and you'll need to post it if you want help.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, The code in place `read_user_input` is just a while loop using `fgetc(stdin)` constantly checking if it equals a newline character or EOF and if not adding it to a `char*` buffer allocated on the heap if that helps ,but what I'm looking for is a way to pipe in input to the program regardless of how `read_user_input` is implemented.

Comment: @NateEldredge Hey, I'm wanting to be able to pipe the output of a command to a process that takes input one after another and calls `fpurge` inbetween each input call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is going to end up reading more data than it needed to resolve the first call to `read_user_input` if it's available, which will result in `__fpurge` discarding the rest. A quick hack to avoid this is `sleep`:

```
(echo 3; sleep 1; echo HelloWorld) | program
```

That will result in the second line not being sent to `program` until after `__fpurge` runs, so it will be available to the second call to `read_user_input`.

Of course, this is somewhat fragile and hacky, so if this were your own program and not a CTF that you can't edit the source of, you should have reworked it to not do `__fpurge`.